# Calculating multiple convex hull volumes using convhulln in R

Tags: r, loops, geometry

I would like to calculate hundreds of convex hull volumes in R, without having to create separate data frames for each calculation.

Here is a simplified example: I currently have a data frame `df` with 3 columns: `Group`, `X`, `Y`.

```
Group<-c(rep("Frank",times=6),rep("Greg",times=11),rep("Stacy",times=3),rep("Nancy",times=10))
X<-c(4,5,3,5,7,4,8,23,4,7,5,2,8,5,8,3,6,5,4,6,8,9,2,5,8,3,6,3,3,4)  
Y<-c(7,9,3,6,4,8,7,8,6,3,2,3,6,7,4,6,8,9,5,7,8,9,6,5,4,6,7,8,3,6)
df<-data.frame(Group,as.numeric(X),as.numeric(Y))
```

For each variable in `Group` I would like to calculate a convex hull volume from the `X` and `Y` data within the `df`. Each `Group` variable has a different length of `x,y` points. The long route for calculating these volumes, which I did, was to make separate data.frames for each `Group`. For example:

```
Frank.frame<-cbind(df$X[df$Group=="Frank"],df$Y[df$Group=="Frank"])
```

I then calculated the convex hull volume from that data

```
library(geometry)
convhulln(Frank.frame, option="FA")$vol
```

My question is: can I perform all the `convhulln` calculations using the original `df`, or is it required that I analyse these individual `Groups` separately?

I have tried to loop this, though am failing to identify the individual groupings, and am instead getting the total Convex hull volume.

```
    for(i in 1:length(unique(df$Group))){ 
             z[i]<-convhulln(cbind(df$X,df$Y),option="FA")$vol
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use as.numeric() on items thaat are already of that class. It just messes up the names of columns. This is standard approach to using `lapply` on a `split` dataframe:

```
> df<-data.frame(Group,X,Y)
> lapply( split( df, df$Group), 
          function (d) convhulln(data.matrix(d[ , c("X","Y")]), option="FA")$vol )
$Frank
[1] 13

$Greg
[1] 64

$Nancy
[1] 29.5

$Stacy
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`purrr`](https://github.com/hadley/purrr) package, we can also do it like this, avoiding the anonymous function:

```
df <- data.frame(Group,X,Y)

library(purrr)
df %>% 
  split(.$Group) %>% 
  map(~ as.matrix(.[ , c("X","Y")])) %>%
  map(~ convhulln(., option="FA")) %>% 
  map_dbl("vol")

Frank  Greg Nancy Stacy 
 13.0  64.0  29.5   3.0
```